# Run script on GCP instance delete action, list actions taken on instance using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Looking for a solution to execute shutdown-script on GCP instance, only if its delete action. Also, is there anyway to distinguish action taken on instance using `gcloud`?

Comment: Which action do you want to perform on "onDelete" event? What's the difference with stop event?

Comment: I want to check few things on instance using script before deleting instance. We usually do stop/start, so don't want it to execute on stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shutdown script is executed when an instance is shut down. Deleting an instance (while it's running) triggers a shutdown request. Therefore, executing a shutdown script only when deleting instances are not possible.

It's also described here in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#shutdown_actions), where the shutdown-script is triggered when instance **shuts down** due to an [`instances.delete`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/delete) request or an [`instances.stop`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop) request to the API.

---

**Edit:** you can see the lists of actions taken on a VM (i.e start/stop/delete) via CLI using the command `gcloud logging read`. For example, this command will display a day's worth of logs on table with columns consisting of Timestamp, Resource Name, and Method Name:

```
gcloud logging read \
"resource.type=gce_instance \
resource.labels.instance_id=INSTANCE_ID \
logName=projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" \
--format="table(timestamp,protoPayload.resourceName,protoPayload.methodName)" \
--project=PROJECT_ID
```

*Note: Replace the capitalized variables with your VM's Instance ID and your Project ID.*

For more information how the command works, see the following resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry

Comment: Okay, Is there anyway to list actions on command line for specific instance ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Are you referring on checking the audit logs of your VM using `gcloud`? If so, please check this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging#viewing_logs. Let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: Yes, looking for glcloud option to list action taken on VM , i.e start/stop/delete

Comment: @SarwarKori I updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: It helped me to see actions performed on instance . Once again Thank you so much :) @Dondi

Comment: @SarwarKori glad to hear it. If I answered your question, please accept my answer by clicking the check mark besides it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.